# BASH: Basic if then and variable assignment

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm used to csh, so this is kinda irritating having to use bash.  What is wrong with this code?

```
if[$time > 0300] && [$time < 0900]
then
$mod=2
else
$mod=0
fi
```

Comment: That's not valid `csh`, either.

Answer (score 37):

By standard it should be

```
if [ "$time" -gt 300 ] && [ "$time" -lt 900 ]
then
   mod=2
else
   mod=0
fi
```

In normal shell scripts you use `[` and `]` to test values. There are no arithmetic-like comparison operators like `>` and `<` in `[ ]`, only `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge`, `-eq` and `-ne`.

When you're in bash, `[[ ]]` is preferred since variables are not subject to splitting and pathname expansion. You also don't need to expand your variables with `$` for arithmetic comparisons.

```
if [[ time -gt 300 && time -lt 900 ]]
then
   mod=2
else
   mod=0
fi
```

Also, using `(( ))` for arithmetic comparisons could be best for your preference:

```
if (( time > 300 && time < 900 ))
then
   mod=2
else
   mod=0
fi
```

Comment: Thanks.  Crazy sensitive this bash is.  I typed what you had, and got erors like ./read.sh: line 14: =0: command not found

But when I copy and pasted your code directly, it worked.  Do you have to always indent 3 spaces before "mod=2" ?

Comment: @Corepuncher It's not necessary. Indent style is anyone's option in shell scripting. I think you tried to add `$` to `mod` when assigning a value to it? `$mod=0`. In bash it would be interpreted as an expansion of `$mod` which is an empty string plus `=0`.

Comment: Bash needs to be sensitive about whitespace because something like `FOO= bar` is interpreted as running the command `bar` in an environment where `FOO` is set to the empty string.

Comment: will mod exist outside the scope of the if , if it hasn't been declared before?

Comment: @Mehdi Yes it will.